# how to alter multiple tables using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to alter multiple tables using regex,

```
ALTER tablename DROP INDEX feed
```

the following are the table names

```
wp_1_ai1ec_event_feeds
wp_12_ai1ec_event_feeds
wp_14_ai1ec_event_feeds
wp_19_ai1ec_event_feeds
```

and so on..

I tried using regex in place of tablename

```
alter wp_[0-9]+_ai1ec_event_feeds drop index feed
```

but I get syntax error. How to achieve this?

Comment: You probably can't do that with plain SQL. May you use some sort of scripting language, such as PHP?

Comment: Is there any way to at least first show the tables that match regex and then write separate queries and execute them?

Comment: Yes. You can use [`SHOW TABLES;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html) with either `LIKE` (simple regex) or `WHERE` (more possibilities).

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the table names using [`SHOW TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html), then do the `ALTER` queries for each of these tables.

To fetch the table names, you can use the simple `LIKE` matching:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'wp\_%\_ai1ec\_event\_feeds';
```

This will work as long as there are no tables like `wp_letters_ai1ec_event_feeds`.